# Blank page instead of "Index of /" in one folder of a website

Tags: apache

An (old) friend of mine has a website (Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server) since many years. He provide, in several folders, several PDF files (research papers from he). He is yet very old (over 80) and probably has made a mistake.

Since few days, in one of these folders, the content is entirely blank, instead of displaying the usual "Index of /".

In all other folders, the website display the content correctly, e.g.:
[image]

But in this particular folder, it's blank (no "Index of /", no "Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server", nothing).

What might have happened? The files in the blank folder are still accessibles with the complete path (e.g. at "http://www.someWebSite.com/folder1/subfolder/paper.pdf" if "subfolder" is the blank folder).

I don't have great knowledge in websites, Apache and so on, but I like helping this friend. Is there a missing configuration file? Bad permissions? He uses the software FileZilla for managing his website. What can or must be controlled?

Comment: Most servers disable the index feature for folders for security reasons.  His hosting service might have updated the server and changed the settings for the site.  If you put in a ticket with his hosting service they might be willing to change it back.

Comment: @DaveS I don't think it's the explanation: all other folders which contain only PDFs are displayed correctly (an "Index of /" and a list of files). Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because there was an "index.html" file in the folder. After removing it, the correct displaying has returned.